# Latency penalty for using istio or other sidecar proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am playing with an idea of using istio for some of the features, however I find it hard to find any reasonable estimates of the latency it adds to every call. 1ms for every service call seems like a lot, especially once there are 10 services involved in a chain, each having request&response passing through istio.

Has anybody measured latency penalty for having sidecar proxy introduced?

Comment: I would surprised if it was 1ms, localhost to localhost packets are highly optimized in the kernel.

Comment: The Istion documetation says "The server-side proxy alone adds 2ms to the 90th percentile latency." from https://istio.io/docs/concepts/performance-and-scalability/. Istio documentation points to a bench mark and results.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://medium.com/@michael_87395/benchmarking-istio-linkerd-cpu-at-scale-5f2cfc97c7fa) does a benchmark of Istio and Linkerd to compare both service meshes in different aspects like CPU, memory or latency.

Answer (score 0):

Istio provides performance numbers, including latency, here: https://istio.io/docs/concepts/performance-and-scalability/#latency-for-istio-hahahugoshortcode-s2-hbhb

From the page...

> The default configuration of Istio 1.1 adds 8ms to the 90th percentile latency of the data plane over the baseline.